# EGOTableViewPullRefresh - how to use it?

Tags: iphone

How embarrasing indeed, but I am unable to work out how to install or implement EGOTableViewPullRefresh.  I really would appreciate a push in the right direction.

I have downloaded the source, and I've included it in my project.

In my view controller class I have replaced : UITableView with : EGORefreshTableHeaderView - but that's giving all sorts of problems.

I searched for several hours on Google, and read all the related topics here.

I am missing something fundamental because I also wasn't able to install the JSON stuff I got on github either.   So I really would appreciate the help - which I could use for these kinds of things in the future.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Else try this one.. https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

Easy to use just insert the classes to your project and change your interface file of the corresponding class like this:

@interface news : PullRefreshTableViewController

Good luck!

Comment: Hi - thank you very much. I will give this a go and update you later. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. Copy `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` folder to your project, add `EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate` delegate to your `viewcontrollerclass.h` and implement the following methods:

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource
- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view
- (BOOL)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceIsLoading:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view
```